# C# ASP NET WEB API ошибка "Соединение сброшено"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Создал простой проект ASPNET.core Web api(ни чего не изменял), при запуске приложения, Visual studio открывает браузер на странице с контролером, но появляется ошибка "Соединение сброшено", с чем это может быть связанно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проделал те же самые шаги - [все работает](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ZDU.png). Курите логи, обновляйте студию, обновляйте SDK

Comment: @tym32167 в этом то и проблема, дома на печке всё работает, а на рабочем отказывается